# unable to execute "normalize-audio out/*.wav" from java

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute "normalize-audio out/*.wav" command from java. for single file as follows,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("normalize-audio 0002.wav");
```

it works fine. but, when i use,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("normalize-audio out/*.wav");
```

it says:

```
     file *.wav: No such file or directory
```

any idea, how i can achieve this?

Comment: Running all files under a directory first access dir get all file name end with .wav than provide specific path like C:/Sound/file.wav

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of the `*` glob is, when you call your script "normally", carried out by the shell.  That is, bash or cmd.exe or whatever you're using, sees the `*` as a special character and carries out some logic to expand it into the set of actual filenames that match.  Then, the script is actually executed passing in these explicit filenames as the argument(s).

So, you have two options:

1. **Do the same yourself**.  Query the files in the appropriate directory, find all of them that match the `*.wav` pattern, then build these up into the argument string.  So instead of invoking exec passing `*.wav` as an argument to your script, you'd end up passing something like `0001.wav 0002.wav 0007.wav`.
2. **Get bash to do it**.  If you invoke `bash` as the program, and then pass in your command as a string, then bash will do its glob expansion as normal.  This would look something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c normalize-audio out/*.wav");`.  The downsides to this are firstly that you're now much less portable (you have requirements about third-party software existing on the PATH), and also that you can get into all sorts of tangles with escaping quotes in your invocation.

Comment: 2nd approach works with other commands such as "ls out/*" but doesn't work with "normalize-audio out/*". i don't know what the reason is